# Using Vbscript or any other XP supported scripting language how would I restore a application that is minimized to system tray?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to restore an application from the system tray using vbscript or other XP supported scripting language Java S.-etc.

This way I could restore the app if running in the tray rather than open a new window. I can use a batch script to check if its running and then run the script otherwise just start the application.

The app I'm referring to is Mozilla Firefox 3.6 and is equipped with the addon MinToTray Revived. I will go into depth about the issue with this app if requested and why this is needed. I have enough addons and would like to keep from installing third party soft . . .

I am experienced with batch scripting but not with others :(

I hope there is a work around for this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AutoIt (http://www.autoitscripting.com), it has very rich automation capabilities.
Basically, you could do nearly everything VBS could do, and much more.

The language has simple VB-like syntax and the manual is one of the best I've ever seen.

Concerning your tasks - one of AutoIt's puproses is GUI automation of already launched applications, so, you can get a window handle and run all the possible commands - maximize, minimize, close, and so on, in just several lines.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reponse I'm using this line of code: WinSetState("[CLASS:MozillaUIWindowClass]", "", @SW_RESTORE)